# How to migrate Joomla database to OpenCart?

Tags: joomla, opencart

How to migrate Joomla database to OpenCart?

Answer (score 0):

You can cofigure manuel export to sql format all data what you need through phpmyadmin (like example).

Or you can use one of the plugins to export to cvs format.

http://extensions.joomla.org/

search "cvs export" - use plugin for your component.